# CanCan::Ability where is the current_user method defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Pretty much what I have mentioned in the title. I am using CanCan::Ability in my code to check permissions and abilities. It expects a current_user method to be defined. I am guessing it comes from devise (but not sure), and I wish to override it. Whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's found [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L352) in the source code. It's nothing to do with devise, though. The documentation is found above the method and describes overwriting it.

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` is implemented by devise [in this eval'ed block](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55) (which, I believe is called indirectly by the `devise_for(:user)` in your `config/routes.rb`). If you want to override it, you should be able to define your own `current_user` method in your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: So if I override current_user in my ApplicationController, will the same current_user will be passed in devise_for? I want that devise's current_user is passed in the devise_for function and my overridden current_user is used in my application code.