# Override current_user in ApplicationController throws undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Based on stackoverflow question for overriding current_user of devise, I wrote something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
    def current_user
        if !devise_current_user.nil?
            return # my logic
        end
        return nil
    end
end
```

Two questions:
1. It throws an undefined method error where I define alias_method ....
2. In the devise_for method, will my overriden current_user will be passed or the devise's current_user?

Comment: Could you please share the link to the question you followed

Comment: Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461347/cancanability-where-is-the-current-user-method-defined and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349606/where-to-override-current-user-helper-method-of-devise-gem