# devise_current_user and current_user questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In My ApplicationController class, I need to override the devise's current_user to use my own definition, but in some cases I also want the devise's current_user. I tried something like

```
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
def current_user
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get an undefined method current_user on the alias_method line. I have already asked this question elsewhere ( [Override current_user in ApplicationController throws undefined method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465324/override-current-user-in-applicationcontroller-throws-undefined-method-error) ) but since it is not answered, I was wondering if I can do something like:

```
def devise_current_user
  return Devise::Controllers::Helpers.current_user
end
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do what you did:

```
def devise_current_user
  current_user
end
```

Comment: it only works if your user model is named User and only after that user is authenticated. Otherwise current_user will return nil. If you are using something other than User, for example AdminUser, then you can use current_admin_user etc.