# Where is current_user defined and managed in my autogenerated rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, metaprogramming

I used the [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) to generate a Rails application that uses the devise, rolify, and cancan gems.

I noted that I can make use of the current_user method.

When I use cmd-shif-F in Textmate to search my project, I do not find where current_user is defined.  I've worked through some roll-your-own authentication logic examples and it seems commonplace to set current_user in the application controller.  No such code is present in my app.

Still, I can verify that current_user functions and is valid.

This SO Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461347/cancanability-where-is-the-current-user-method-defined) points to some code, but I don't get it.  Looks like current_user is a generated method that is the result of some metaprogramming wizardry.  Still, if it is not referenced in a before filter in the application controller, how can it be working?

The fairly bare application_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

end
```

Comment: Thx.  I see what looks like a 'metadefinition' in devise/controllers/helpers.rb  Still, how is it invoked with each RESTful iteration if its declaration is outside application_controller ?